# How to connect to azure SQL database without IP whitelisting

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

Someone at the interview asked me a question.
Lets assume there is a new SQL Server being provisioned in the resource group. The question was how would you establish a connectin using azure data factory without whitelisting the IP address.

I responded that we could use Managed Identity.

Could someone guide me to the best practices around it. The securest way to connect to Azure SQL DB.

I answered Managed Identity. However not sure about this.

Comment: Thanks, Nandan, it does. Do you know any good reads on this topic that you are aware of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed identity is just a type of authentication to access the Database and the best secure way to access it. But that is not the answer for your query w.r.t whitelisting .

[image]

you need to enable this property

Comment: This would mean the Azure services would communicate with each other directly without the need of whitelisting